# how to use fragment in android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application which support android 2.2 library.In this app I want to use fragment
someone suggest me ,if possible how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes you need to use the support library. What is important to know is that you can use the support library on honeycomb and icecream sandwich as well. In that way you can use the same build on all the platforms.
You need to use the SDK 4.0 as target with minsdk 2.2. 
A different problem are the settings activities. For Honeycomb+ you can use the PreferenceFragment that are not supported by the support library yet.
If you use the new onBuildHeaders method of PreferenceActivity and the "header" tag in the settings.xml you need to put that xml in a separated folder like for example xml-v12 to specify that it is used only with API-12+.

For the settings have a look to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html
there is a good example of the onBuildHeaders

For the support library:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Something I need to add: I have implemented this solution and almost  everything works fine. In one case when I remove a fragment using TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE it does not work. The same code works on 2.3 with the support lib and on honeycomb if I do not use the support lib. To keep using the support lib on Honeycomb I had to use TRANSIT_NONE. It looks a bug in the support lib but I did not have time to investigate more.

Comment: is there any simple tutorials for fragments ?

Answer (score 5):

I think that, in order to include fragment in Android 2.2, you need to add `android-support-v4.jar` to your project.

Answer (score 4):

Right click the Android project you want to add Fragment support for.

- Build Path->Configure Build Path
- Libraries tab
- Add External JARs
- Add the android-support-v4.jar (should be in the android downloads
  folder under extras/android/support/v4

Also don't forget to use `getSupportFragmentManager` in place of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), aka the v4 compatibility library for that.